# How do I add JavaScript to a master page?

Tags: javascript

I want to add the following JavaScript to my master page.

```
<script 
    type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://voap.weather.com/weather/oap/USGA0028?template=OTDRV&par=3000000007&unit=0&key=twciweatherwidget">
</script>
```

How can I add the above Weather Channel script to my master page?

When I add it in my right column it displays twice with different results.

Comment: you need to provide code snippets in order for anyone to be able to effectively help you. The information you have provided will not serve to find a solution.

Comment: I edited his question. Code is there but wrong formatted. It has to be reviewed until my edit becomes public.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it once in the place you want it displayed and it should display (once).

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/MLmsm/

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just copy it in your page...

Works here
http://jsfiddle.net/JmRAx/